# File with CSS and JS files not serving on server and prints ��U�v�8��+

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, hapi.js

When I run my hapijs app locally it is working but when I deploy it in the server it doesn't work. The page can serve html files but if the HTML file has css or bootsrap then it prints weird 
symbols like ��U�v�8��+

The link that shows the weird response : https://us-central1-fir-app-85853.cloudfunctions.net/v1/teacher/list

Here is my index.js file.

How can I fix this issue?

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const api = require('./server');

exports.v1 = functions.https.onRequest(async (event, resp) => {
  let server = await api.startServer();
  const options = {
    method: event.httpMethod,
    headers: event.headers,
    url: event.path,
    payload: event.body
  };

  return server
    .inject(options)
    .then(response => {
        delete response.headers['content-encoding']
        delete response.headers['transfer-encoding']
        response.headers['x-powered-by'] = 'hapijs'
        resp.set(response.headers);
        return resp.status(response.statusCode).send(response.result);
    })
    .catch(error => resp.status(500).send(error.message || "unknown error"));
});
```

Here is my full source code on github https://github.com/kartikgreen/hapijs-firebase

Comment: What is the file you deploy to cloudfront? How do you produce it?

Comment: It is a cloud function that deploys the hapi js app and starts it.

Comment: it is not CloudFront it is firebase

Comment: @9000 It is similar Aws lambda

Comment: It seem to response fine, what is response.result that you're sending back?  Can you post the server code and how you're using css and bootstrap may help.

Comment: @noobius, I have added my source code link in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed the 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br' line in the request headers' object to not request gzip compression.

This answer is already in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38588717/9821336)

Answer (score -1):

This is very likely a character encoding issue.

There are a few causes, one is a different character encoding being outputted than UTF-8.

so say your document outputs in ISO-8859-1 (known as Latin-1), if you do not set the character set the browser will default to UTF-8. Think of it like outputting chinese and then asking a language parser to treat it as japanese, it will never understand!

Not sure how to do it in hapjs but in PHP you would just add a header as follows:-

`header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");`

The other possible cause is a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark).

If your script is accidentally outputting some blank data before it should this can add these invisible characters.

There are loads of answers on BOMs on Stack Overflow so I won't repeat those.

I would normally say run the page through the [W3C Internationalisation Checker](https://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/#validate-by-uri+) but your page seems to kill it (which could be down to firebase). Perhaps you could capture the raw output to a file and run it through that way?

Comment: I have added my GitHub project link. The code is in functions folder. I added the header but it dint work.